# Dart comments: literal

Tags: dart, comments

```
/// MyType<String>
```

Needs to be written as

```
/// MyType&lt;String&gt;
```

Which is less readable.

In javadoc, it has @literal.

```
 {@literal
    MyType<String>
 }
```

Does dart has similar feature?

Comment: dartdoc uses Markdown syntax.  You should surround `MyType<String>` with square brackets (`[ ]`) to create a reference or use backticks for code.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way for providing doc for method parameters? In java, @param can be used.

Comment: Not really.  https://dart.dev/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-prose-to-explain-parameters-return-values-and-exceptions